# Show that recurrence is $O(\phi^{\log n})

Tags: asymptotics

I have a function whose time complexity is given by the following recurrence:

\begin{equation*}
    T(n) = \begin{cases}
               \mathcal{O}(1) & \text{for } n=0\\
               T(k)+T(k-1)+\mathcal{O}(1)  & \text{for } n=2k\\
               T(k)+\mathcal{O}(1) & \text{for } n=2k+1\\
           \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

and I have to prove that $$T(n)\in \mathcal{O}(\phi^{\log_2 n}),$$

where $\phi$ is the golden ratio, $(1 + \sqrt5)\over2$.

I think I could prove it by induction but, how would I go on about it if I didn't know that $T(n)\in \mathcal{O}(\phi^{\log_2 n})$ in the first place?

Comment: is $\phi$ here the golden ratio (which is constant)?

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence (shifted by 1) is known as Stern's diatomic sequence, or the Stern–Brocot sequences. The usual recurrence is:
\begin{align}
&a(0)=0 \\ &a(1)=1 \\ &a(2n) = a(n) \\ &a(2n+1) = a(n) + a(n+1)
\end{align}
The recurrence suggests that the answer has something to do with binary representation, so one might be prompted to look at the maximal value of $a(n)$ among numbers of length $m$ in binary:
$$
1,2,3,5,8,13,\ldots
$$
This is the Fibonacci sequence. (One can check that the first maxima are attained at $(2^n-(-1)^n)/3$.)

From here, one immediately sees that the rate of growth is $O(\phi^{\log_2 n})$.

More can be said. For example, Coons and Tyler determined the best possible constant in front of $\phi^{\log_2 n}$ in their paper [The maximal order of Stern's diatomic sequence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1521).

You can find many more links in the OEIS entry [A002487](http://oeis.org/A002487).